# Hide jquery dialogs by id in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, dialog

I got an index page with a list of objects(@contacts), and i need an ability to edit every @contact entry in a popup using ajax. List of objects:

```rails
  <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
    <div><%= contact.name %> | <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_contact_path(contact), :id => "edit_contact_dialog_link_#{contact.id}" %></div>
    <% @contact = contact %><%= render :template => "contacts/edit" %>
  <% end %>
```

Here I'm adding an unique id to all edit links. Doing as well in `edit.html.erb`:

```
<div id="edit_contact_dialog_<%= @contact.id %>">
  <h1>Editing contact</h1>
  <%= render 'form' %>
</div>
```

Now on index page I have a list of the contacts(with unique edit links `edit_contact_dialog_link_ID`), and edit forms(with unique div ids `edit_contact_dialog_ID`)

I need to hide all `edit_contact_dialog_ID` boxes and on every `edit_contact_dialog_link_ID` click open corresponding dialog window, but don't know how.

My `contacts.js`:

```
  $("#edit_contact_dialog_(here i need a regexp or smthng?)").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 455,
    modal: true
  });

  $("#edit_contact_dialog_link_???").click(function(){
    $("#edit_contact_dialog_???").dialog("open");
    return false;
  });
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the class attribute

```
$(".dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 455,
    modal: true
});

$(".edit_handler").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#edit_contact_dialog_" + id).dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```